# How to register a package Id for a android app in publisher account

Tags: android, google-play

I just registered a google play publisher account. But i need a bundle Id or package Id for my app. How can i get this from the console?. Not able to find any option .

Answer (score 0):

A bundle ID otherwise known as a package in Android is the unique identifier for all Android apps. It needs to be unique as when you upload it to Google Play it identifies and publishes your app using the package name as the unique app identification.

In Java, and in Android, you typical use a reverse domain name ie: com.whatever.stuff to ensure uniquness. If you don't have a domain to use, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535798/whats-the-convention-for-java-package-names-without-a-domain-association) I asked for a number of ther useful ideas. The Accepted answer there is the one I use: `com.gmail.name.android_app_name`

Note: if you use Eclipse, or a simular IDE when you first set up your project, it asked you for the package name, and that is what play store is looking for -

[image]

Comment: Yes, but when you register for a google play publisher account, does it reserve you a common partial bundle id like com.exampleCompany.* or can we use any bundle id until its not used by anyone till date?..like com.google.exampleCompany or com.gmail.test etc?..

Comment: @Koncorde - When you register as a publisher you do not get anything special in terms of a domain to use or a package prefix. You can use anything you want as long as it is unique, the uniqueness is guaranteed by using a specific domain or email (since there can't be more then one of those) and post-fixed with your app name